# I am wanting to make a simple calculator using python and a for loop. Any way I can make it work?

Tags: python, math, calculator

I'm trying to make a calculator that acts as a 'Number Wikipedia.' Basically, it gives information of two numbers, including adding, subtracting, multiplying, dividing, squaring, etc. For the first part, I wanted to use a for loop to print the adding, subtracting, multiplying, and dividing part. Here's the code:

```
def number_wikipedia(x,y):
  ops = ['+','-','*','/']
  for op in ops:  
    print(f'{x}{op}{y} =')
```

How would I use a similar method to print the actual results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use eval()

```
print(eval(f'{x}{op}{y}'))
```

Comment: That does not work. There is either a missing `'` or an extraneous one.
This works: `print(eval("{}{}{}".format(x,op,y)))`.

Comment: Edited, just remove the double quotes

Comment: Still missing a quote at the end of the string.

Comment: Sorry, typo :-)

Comment: Please read: [Eval really is dangerous](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html).

Answer (score 4):

You can replace your operator strings with actual operators, to start:

```py
import operator

ops = {'+': operator.add, '-': operator.sub, '*': operator.mul, '/': operator.truediv}
```

Then use these in your loop:

```py
import operator

def number_wikipedia(x, y):
    ops = {'+': operator.add, '-': operator.sub, '*': operator.mul, '/': operator.truediv}

    for opname, op in ops.items():
        print(f"{x}{opname}{y} = {op(x, y)}")
```

```
>> number_wikipedia(2,3)

2+3 = 5
2-3 = -1
2*3 = 6
2/3 = 0.6666666666666666
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I'll use eval, but good to know!

Comment: @JarodL Just make sure you understand how and what `eval` does, and when it can be dangerous.

Comment: @JarodL Please be aware that `eval` is a giant security breach.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize. I'll use your method.